# Group by and Aggregate in ms sql

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate

`dbo.edp_GetNumDaysInMonth()`  is a user defined function.

```
select 
   month(a.enddatetime),
cast(((dbo.edp_GetNumDaysInMonth(a.enddatetime)) * 22.5 - (isnull(sum(a.delayhr),0)/3600.00)) / count(a.machine_no) as decimal(11,2)) as MTBF 
from mro_maint a 
   left join mro_machine b on a.machine_no = b.machine_no 
where (b.section = 'TRANSMISSION' OR b.section = 'EATON LINE' OR b.section = 'TOYOTA') 
group by month(a.enddatetime)
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'a.enddatetime' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `month(a.enddatetime)` so in your select you have to use:

- `month(a.enddatetime)` or
- a field inside an aggregate function

You are using `a.enddatetime` so you have an error.

In this case probably you can use `min(a.enddatetime)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx

```
GROUP BY Month(SomeDate) -- or -- GROUP BY DatePart(month, SomeDate)
```

> Unless you are constraining the data so that it covers only 1 year,
>   and it will always cover exactly 1 year, you should never just group
>   by the Month of a date since it only returns a number from 1-12, not
>   an actual "month".  Thus, data for January 2006 and January 2007 will
>   be consolidated together into "month 1", which is probably not what
>   you want.  Overall, I recommend avoiding grouping only on a month
>   number for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use group by with any field it should have aggregate function with select option.

So you can use MAX, MIN etc. as per requirement with select field